# copy label text to input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have tried several ways to achieve this, but somehow nothing works for this.

How can I copy the "label text" of respective Radio Button, which is selected by user into the input field (Result Box) in real time?

HTML -

```
<ul class="gfield_radio" id="input_4_4">
    Radio Buttons:  
    <br />
    <li class="gchoice_4_0">
        <input name="input_4" type="radio" value="2" id="choice_4_0" class="radio_s" tabindex="4">
        <label for="choice_4_0">Hi</label>
    </li>
    <li class="gchoice_4_1">
        <input name="input_4" type="radio" value="4" id="choice_4_1" class="radio_s" tabindex="5">
        <label for="choice_4_1">Hello</label>
    </li>
    <li class="gchoice_4_2">
        <input name="input_4" type="radio" value="3" id="choice_4_2" class="radio_s" tabindex="6">
        <label for="choice_4_2">Aloha</label>
    </li>
</ul>
<br />
<div class="ginput_container">
    Result Box: 
    <br />
    <input name="input_3" id="input_4_3" type="text" value="" class="medium" tabindex="3">
</div>
```

My attempts:

```
$('input').change(function() { 
    if (this.checked) { 
        var response = $('label[for="' + this.id + '"]').html(); 
        alert(response); 
    } 

    // also this:
 //   if ($("input[type='radio'].radio_s").is(':checked')) { 
 //       var card_type = $("input[type='radio'].radio_s:checked").val();               
 //       alert('card_type'); 
 //   } 
});
```

Comment: You said you've tried some ways, can you show the code?

Comment: @MelanciaUK: Instead of doing all of it, I tried to grab and get value associated with the radio button. 

`code`
$('input').change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
     var response = $('label[for="' + this.id + '"]').html();
     alert(response);
    }
   });
`code`

Comment: and this - if($("input[type='radio'].radio_s").is(':checked')) {
     var card_type = $("input[type='radio'].radio_s:checked").val();
     alert('card_type');
    }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to traverse the DOM from the radio which was clicked to find the nearest `label` element.

```
$('.radio_s').change(function() {
    $('#input_4_3').val($(this).closest('li').find('label').text());
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/WQyEw/)

You could also use `$(this).next('label')` however, that relies on the position of the `label` element not changing. My first example means the `label` can be anywhere within the same `li` as the radio button and it will work.

Comment: Thanks a ton. This works. Just an additional question - what if I don't have the class i.e. .radio_s

Comment: @vajrasar you could use the name attribute selector: `$('input[name="input_4"]')`, however this will be slower

Comment: Okay. I think I get the gist. So in the solution you are asking to fill in the text for input element of 'this' event (change in radio_s) where a 'label' is to be found in the 'li' (closest denotes that action). right?

Comment: @vajrasar yep, you got it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.radio_s').click(function() {
$("#input_4_3").val($("input:checked" ).next().text());
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/WQyEw/3/

Answer (score 1):

This is a slightly tricky question to answer well. The structure of your HTML implies that there may be more than one of these structures on the page. So you may have more than one set of radio buttons with a corresponding checkbox.

I have put some working code into [a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lonesomeday/RGXsN/).

I made one change: all the code you had in your question is now in `<div class="container">`. You would need as many of these as you had groups of radio buttons and checkboxes.

You can then have jQuery code like this:

```
$('ul.gfield_radio').on('change', 'input[type="radio"]', function () {
    var label = $('label[for="' + this.id + '"]');
    $(this).closest('.container').find('input.medium').val(label.text());
});
```

This code is not tied to the `id` values in this particular bit of HTML, but would work as many times as necessary throughout the page.

Comment: You are right. This is certainly a part of a big form asking input from user and drafting a post format via compiling the inputs selected by user to be published.

Answer (score 0):

***Why to depend on third party library when you can achieve it with plain javascript:***

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        var a = document.getElementsByName('input_4');
        for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            document.getElementsByName('input_4')[i].addEventListener('change', function () {
                showValue(this);
            }, false);
        }
    }, false);

    function showValue(element) {       
        alert(element.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('label')[0].innerHTML)
    }
</script>
```